# Expansão em Taylor usando funções

Tags: python-3.x

Eu escrevi uma função que calcula o seno de um ângulo usando a expansão em Taylor dada pela expressão sen(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + ... AD INFINITUM. Criei uma função que calcula o fatorial de um número e outra função que calcula o seno usando essa expansão. O cálculo deve ser interrompido quando o próximo termo da expansão for menor do que 10^-10 (em módulo) e isso está expresso no while. Não vejo nenhum erro no código, mas quando rodo o programa o valor que ele devolve é incorreto quando comparo com o valor da calculadora.

```
PI = 3.14159265358979323846

def fatorial(n):
    '''
    Esta função recebe um número inteiro n e devolve
    o seu fatorial.
    '''
    fatorial = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1,1):
        fatorial = fatorial * i
    return fatorial 
        

def seno(theta):
    '''
    Esta função aproxima o valor da função seno para o ângulo theta
    usando a série de Taylor até que o módulo do próximo termo da
    série calculada seja menor 1e-10.
    Entrada: O ângulo theta que deve ser informado em graus.
    Saída: A aproximação do seno do ângulo theta.
    '''
    n = 1
    k = 3
    eps = 10**-10
    theta = (theta*PI)/180
    x = ((-1)**n)*((theta)**k)
    y = fatorial(k)
    while x/y < -eps or x/y > eps:
        theta = theta + (x/y)
        n = n + 1
        k = k + 2
        x = ((-1)**n) * ((theta)**k)
        y = fatorial(k)
    return theta
```

Comment: Seu `while x/y < -eps or x/y > eps:` não deveria ser `while x/y > -eps and x/y < eps:`?